# Using Joomla's baseurl to import javascript

Tags: javascript, uri, joomla1.5

I am trying to use Joomla's basurl to link to my javascript files like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/js/music.js"></script>
```

My code highlighting though seems out of whack and I am wondering if anyone knows how I should be writing this please?

if I use it in the css link everything looks fine there:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/music/css/nav.css" type="text/css" />
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your include css and include js code it seems like your template is called `music`.

Therefore, you need to have your template's name as part of the path. Instead of `/templates/js/` use `/templates/music/js/`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/music/js/music.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I will give this a bash!

Comment: Instead of hard coding the template name you should use <?php echo $this->template; ?>